# why does background-color for division not appear?

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have one `<div>` nested in another. The parent `<div>` has a background image. I want the nested `<div>` to have background-color but it keeps displaying the background-image of its parent.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fca205;
}


#poem {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: black;
}


div {
  width: 30%;
  border: 3px gold solid;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background-image: url("images/TigerPattern.jpg");
}

blockquote {
  color: white;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 16px; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="poem">
    <blockquote>     
      Tiger, tiger, burning bright  
      In the forests of the night,  
      What immortal hand or eye  
      Could frame thy fearful symmetry?  
    </blockquote>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nobody has called a "div" tag a "division" in about 15 years (if ever), and the [tag:division] tag has nothing to do with `<div>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using this:

```
 #poem {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: black;
 }


 div {
    width: 30%;
    border: 3px gold solid;
    margin: 1em auto;
    background-image: url("images/TigerPattern.jpg");
 }
```

So you're defining a background-color for #poem but you then overwrite all properties for `div` element, thus your background property reads like this:

```
#poem{background: url('http://assets.worldwildlife.org/photos/2090/images/hero_small/Sumatran-Tiger-Hero.jpg?1345559303') repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;}
```

Therefore, you need to use this:

```
 body {
     background-color: #fca205;
 }
 #poem {
     width: 70%;
     background: black;
 }
 div {
     width: 30%;
     border: 3px gold solid;
     margin: 1em auto;
     background: url("http://assets.worldwildlife.org/photos/2090/images/hero_small/Sumatran-Tiger-Hero.jpg?1345559303");
 }
 blockquote {
     color: white;
     font-family: Georgia;
     font-size: 16px;
 }
```

or even better, never, ever, ever, assign a property to `div` unless you really need it, better use a `class`

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hjk90w92/)

Answer (score 0):

```
This is working
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
background-color: #fca205;
}


#poem {
width: 70%;

background-color: black;
}


div {
width: 30%;
border: 3px gold solid;
margin: 1em auto;
}
#outer{

 background-image: url("paper.gif");

 }

blockquote {
color: white;
font-family: Georgia;
font-size: 16px;    
}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer" >
 <div id="poem">
    <blockquote>                
    Tiger, tiger, burning bright     
    In the forests of the night,     
    What immortal hand or eye    
    Could frame thy fearful symmetry?    
    </blockquote>
     <br>
     </div>
     </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```